# Remove launch from Run/Debug drop down in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, history

I often have many run configurations that gets in this history which I don't want, like unit tests or when I change project.

I don't want to remove the launch configuration, just remove it from the history list display when I click the little arrow next to the run or debug button.

How to remove launch configuration from Run/Debug drop down containing launch history in Eclipse?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the drop down is displayed, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> on the run configuration history you want to remove. A dialog will open to confirm the deletion.

You can disable the confirmation dialog in Eclipse's preferences: **Window** > **Preferences** > **Run/Debug** > **Launching**: uncheck "Prompt for confirmation when removing a configuration from the launch history".

Comment: Also consider adding those that you really WANT to have in that list as favorites. In the common tab in the launch configuration, check the boxes for the Debug and/or Run menu. They will then always be on top and you can stop worrying about getting all the other ones there as well as they will  always be below these.

Comment: @Matthias - This is useful. However, all of our launches already had these set, so I had to manually uncheck all the ones I didn't want. Now they show up as modified compared to source control. Be nice if there was a way to reorder them.

Comment: Where did you come to know of this shortcut? :)

Comment: @mtk I don't really remember :) Probably somewhere in the documentation or on a blog.

Comment: Eclipse really is *something*… Thanks for the shortcut!